# How to call a simple getter method in Groovy?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, groovy, gradle

I can't believe I have to ask this question, it's really confusing. The goal of this question is to figure out **why** and/or find an easier way (than reflection) to get the correct result.

#### Back story

*I loaded some class files from directories and jar files via a `URLClassLoader` and I'd like to dump all the class names and their declared methods. The classes cannot be initialized (see `false`) because if any code runs in those classes exceptions may be thrown due to some missing dependencies. I ran into this problem while trying to output just the class names.*

#### Question

What am I missing, how can I work around Groovy's magic and just simply call a method (called `getName`) on an object (of type `java.lang.Class`) without reflection? Someone also please point to the specification as to why this work this way.
Here's the output for my mini-test (see below) and my comments:

```
.name // magically initializes class X and calls X.get("name")
name and Y

.getName() // tries to reload class Y in another ClassLoader and initialize it
X and thrown SHOULD NOT INIT

["name"] // this is just plain magic! What a Terrible Failure :)
name and thrown SHOULD NOT INIT

reflection // obviously works, becase it's really explicit
X and Y
```

#### Test harness and test-cases

Changing the test closures to be explicit on the argument type (`Class<?> c ->`) makes no difference.

```groovy
new File("X.java").write('''
    public class X {
        public static String get(String key) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    ''');
new File("Y.java").write('''
    public class Y {
        static {
            if (true) // needed to prevent compile error
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("SHOULD NOT INIT");
        }
    }
    ''');
print 'javac X.java Y.java'.execute().err.text;


def test = { String title, Closure nameOf ->
    URL url = new File(".").toURI().toURL();
    // need a new ClassLoader each time because it remembers
    // if a class has already thrown ExceptionInInitializerError
    ClassLoader loader = java.net.URLClassLoader.newInstance(url);
    // false means not to initialize the class.
    // To get the name of the class there's no need to init
    // as shown in the reflection test.
    // Even fields and methds can be read without initializing,
    // it's essentially just parsing the .class file.
    Class x = Class.forName("X", false, loader);
    Class y = Class.forName("Y", false, loader);

    println()
    println title
    try {
        print nameOf(x)
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        print "thrown " + ex.cause?.message
    }
    print " and "
    try {
        print nameOf(y)
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        print "thrown " + ex.cause?.message
    }
    println()
}

test '.name', { c -> c.name; }
test '.getName()', { c -> c.getName(); }
test '["name"]', { c -> c["name"] }
test 'reflection', { c -> java.lang.Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getName").invoke(c); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the invokedynamic port I can give a clear answer: to bypass a JVM bug in which the JVM made a call to a static method of a class, without calling clinit at all.

As for the other part.... this would be commit https://github.com/apache/incubator-groovy/commit/0653ddc15ec0215f2141159a71c1b12d8d800dbe#diff-59caa62540f88da51c8c91c6656315d5 not sure why Cedric did that. Assuming the JVM works as it should, this should not be needed...

Comment: Can you be more clear on "invokedynamic" and "other"? I'm new to lowlevel JVM stuff.

Comment: Also do you know if there's a way to do what I did with reflection, without reflection?

Comment: As for invokedynamic... On the JVM to make a method call you need to know the receiver and parameter base types as well as the method name. If you want a different logic than having to know all those types at compiler time already, for example because you are a dynamic language, then you cannot use those standard invocation instructions. There are 3 a around it: reflection, runtime class generation, invokedynamic. Groovy uses all of them. reflection and invokedynamic will in the end also generate classes at runtime though...

Comment: But invokedynamic allows you write a fake method call and then provide your own logic for caching and method selection. Though to generate the information for invokedynamic or the runtime generated classes you usually use reflection

Comment: So there is no way around reflection really. The method invocation itself can be done without reflection as do invokedynamic and runtime class generation (though in Groovy the first call with class generation still uses reflection)

Comment: I'm still not fully clear, why I simply can't call a method, it exists, invokedynamic or not, existing method should take precedence. From the source you linked it looks like variables holding Class objects behave differently to allow "dynamic" (= reflective) calls with simple syntax?

Comment: To call a method like Java, you need to know at compile time all the types needed. To call getName() on Class, you have to write something like "invokevirtual Class.getName()" In a dynamic language like Groovy the call can be intercepted or the method replaced, thus you cannot simply write that, even if you know the involved required types. That's why there is a meta class and all the strange invocation logic. And dynamic is not equal to reflective. Only reflective does not allow runtime meta programming or Groovy builder for example.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I have to learn more about Groovy to get this. I still find it really confusing not being able to call an existing method, regardless of "can be intercepted or the method replaced". Because I'm calling a method on `Class`, not `X` or `Y`. It feels similar to: instead of getting 4 for `"list".length()` I get the length of the List stored in local variable named list. I guess they intercepted any calls to any object of type `Class` and doing something similar. Do you know documentation for this?